# MySQL função IN porém meu parâmetro vem uma string

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Olá,

Tenho uma procedure que recebe alguns paramêtros, dentre eles preciso receber uma lista de códigos, que são 10 no máximo. Porém na consulta, estou tentando por

WHERE valor IN(valor1, valor2), porém como trata-se de uma string isto não funciona.

Gostaria de saber como poderia fazer para tratar essa string, tirando as aspas.
Exatamente nesta linha: 
((tp.cod_tipo_guarda IN(**valores**) OR p_cod_tipo_guarda = 0) AND tp.ind_ativo = 1 ) AND

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    a.cod_area,
    a.nom_area,
    tp.cod_tipo_guarda,
    tp.nom_tipo_guarda,
    utp.ind_incluir,
    utp.ind_alterar,
    utp.ind_consultar,
    utp.ind_excluir,
    utp.ind_relatorio,
    utp.ind_alerta_venc,
    COUNT(a1.cod_area) AS users_dono,
    COUNT(a2.cod_area) AS users_backup
FROM 
    tipo_guarda tp
  INNER JOIN AREA a ON tp.cod_area = a.cod_area AND a.cod_area != p_nega
  INNER JOIN usuario u ON u.cod_usuario = p_cod_usuario
  LEFT JOIN usuario_tipo_guarda utp ON utp.cod_tipo_guarda = tp.cod_tipo_guarda AND utp.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario
  LEFT JOIN AREA a1 ON a1.cod_usu_dono = p_cod_usuario AND a.cod_area = a1.cod_area
  LEFT JOIN AREA a2 ON a2.cod_usu_backup = p_cod_usuario AND a.cod_area = a2.cod_area
WHERE 
    (utp.cod_usuario = p_cod_usuario OR utp.cod_usuario IS NULL) AND
    ((tp.cod_tipo_guarda IN(**valores**) OR p_cod_tipo_guarda = 0) AND tp.ind_ativo = 1 ) AND
    ((a.cod_area = p_cod_area OR p_cod_area = 0) AND a.ind_ativo = 1 ) AND
    ((a.cod_usu_backup = p_cod_dono_backup OR p_cod_dono_backup = 0) OR (a.cod_usu_dono = p_cod_dono_backup OR p_cod_dono_backup = 0)) AND
(a.cod_perfil = p_cod_perfil OR p_cod_perfil = 0)
    AND (u.cod_perfil <> 1 ) AND (u.cod_perfil <> 5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso resolve:

```
 ((tp.cod_tipo_guarda IN(TRIM(BOTH "'" FROM valores)) OR p_cod_tipo_guarda = 0) AND tp.ind_ativo = 1 )
```